# PHP, SQL-Query with IN clause troubleshooting

Tags: php, sql

I have some problem with my Code, i tried to solve it on my own but i didnt found any matching solves.

So i have an array with User_ids...

```
var_dump($arr)
array(6) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(6) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(7) }
```

...and i want to get the amount of tasks every user has :)

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`task_id`) AS `amount`, `u_id`, `name` FROM `v_all` WHERE `u_id` IN ($in)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

OUTPUT:

```
var_dump($data);
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["amount"]=> string(2) "14" ["u_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(15) "Max Mustermann" } }
```

my problem is, that i was expecting 6 Users, not only 1.
Im kinda stuck here, 
hope u can help me :D

Thx a lot ^^

Comment: Can you provide resulting query string. Something like `var_dump($sql);`

Comment: This is due to your use of the _aggregate function_ `COUNT`, without explicitly specifying proper `GROUP BY` criteria.

Comment: @04FS oh man :D now my results are displayed as i want it :)
Thanks for your answer, you really helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "04FS" i could solve my problem! Now my results are displayed correctly :) Thanks alot

- This is due to your use of the aggregate function COUNT, without explicitly specifying 
  proper GROUP BY criteria. – 04FS 10 mins ago